# Textbox Change Event Error on Backspace --VBA Userform

Tags: excel, onchange, userform, vba

I have 2 Text boxes on a user form: tbQty1, tbQty2.  I want tbQty2 value to equal tbQty1.value * 2. The following simple code [_Change()] works unless I delete or backspace out the value of tbQty1.  I get an run time error 13 type mismatch

```
Private Sub tbQty1_Change()

tbQty2.Value = tbDoorQty.Value * 2

End Sub
```

I have tried IF statements with tbQty1.value = "" etc. and Keypress (`IF KeyAscii = 8 Then tbQty1 = ""`). All blew up the same way  I'm just missing something.  Thanks for the help

Comment: EDIT: tbDoorQty Should be tbQty1 in this example.  Code was amended.

Comment: try if isnumeric(tbQty1.value) then , This would check if its not blank and numeric

Comment: Sivaprasath -- nice, it works.  I paired with another IF so the second text box is cleared if the first has a "" value.  Answer instead of comment and I can check 'answered' if you want.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If isnumeric(tbQty1.value) then
 'statements
end if
```